# How can I send a character with Async Pro TApdComPort?

Tags: c++, serial-port, rad-studio

I am trying to communicate with an Arduino using a C++ interface that I developed on RAD Studio 10.2 Tokyo. For the serial communication, I use Async Pro Library.

The code in the Arduino works well. I can send a specific character without difficulty. If the LED is off, sending an 'a' turns it on; if the LED is on, sending an 'a' turns it off.

When I use the interface I developed, the LED flashes and goes out.

The code is very simple:

```
ApdComPort1->Open = true;
ApdComPort1->Output = 'a';
ApdComPort1->Open = false;
```

I don't understand what I'm missing. Do I have to setup baud and other `TApdComPort` parameters?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Arduino, but for serial (COMM) communications you have to set the baud rate, the parity, etc.

You also have to know what the protocol is (what data to send and the format of what you are sending - actually what the receiver is expecting).